# Child Row not Expanding after applying virtualization using react-virtualized in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table, react-virtualized

I am trying to achieve virtualization for material-table using react-virtualized. Being noob with regards to virtualization, I am unable to figure out the issue.

**Here is the link to sandbox** : **https://codesandbox.io/s/virtualized-material-table-react-virtualized-forked-1j590r**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.